# Playing fetched video url in RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have used RecyclerView to diplay the list of my parsed JSON data.It contains video url.Now i want to play these videos in that list.So my first question is what will be the best approach to do it (i.e ExoPlayer,MediaPlayer,SurfaceView, TextureView or else) and second question is how to implement that through recyclerview adapter.Please help me.

**Code in Context**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Http Connection";

    private List<Live> liveList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LiveAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        final String url = "My URL";



        new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);
    }

    public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

            InputStream inputStream = null;

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            Integer result = 0;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                if (statusCode==200){
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                    String response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

                    parseResult(response);

                    result = 1;

                }else{
                    result = 0;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            if(result == 1){
                mAdapter = new LiveAdapter(getApplicationContext(),liveList);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch data!");
            }
        }

    }

    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line = "";
        String result = "";

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            result += line;
        }

            /* Close Stream */
        if(null!=inputStream){
            inputStream.close();
        }

        return result;
    }
    private void parseResult(String result) {

        try{
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);

            String code = response.getString("code");

            JSONObject results = response.optJSONObject("result");

            JSONArray live = results.optJSONArray("live");

            for(int i=0; i< live.length();i++ ){
                JSONObject lives = live.optJSONObject(i);

                Live l=new Live();
                l.id = lives.getString("id");
                l.title = lives.getString("title");
                l.category_id = lives.getString("category_id");
                l.category  = lives.getString("category");
                l.url = lives.getString("url");
                l.thumbnail_small=lives.getString("thumbnail_small");
                l.thumbnail_large=lives.getString("thumbnail_large");
                l.thumbnail_banner=lives.getString("thumbnail_banner");
                l.type=lives.getString("type");
                l.likes=lives.getString("likes");
                l.watch=lives.getString("watch");

                liveList.add(i,l);

            }

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**LiveAdapter.java**

```
public class LiveAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LiveAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private static String TAG = "LiveAdapter";

    private List<Live> liveList;
    private Context context;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, ids, category_id,category,type,like,watch;
        public ImageView ts,tl,tb;
        public VideoView url;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ids = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
            category_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_id);
            category = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category);
            url = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.url);
            ts = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ts);
            tl = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tl);
            tb = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tb);
            type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.type);
            like = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.like);
            watch = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.watch);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

        }
    }


    public LiveAdapter(Context context, List<Live> liveList) {
        this.liveList = liveList;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Live live = liveList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(live.getTitle());
        holder.ids.setText(live.getId());
        holder.category_id.setText(live.getCategory_id());
        holder.category.setText(live.getCategory());
        holder.type.setText(live.getType());
        holder.like.setText(live.getLikes());
        holder.watch.setText(live.getWatch());
        Picasso.with(context).load(liveList.get(position).getThumbnail_small()).resize(120, 60).into(holder.ts);
        Picasso.with(context).load(liveList.get(position).getThumbnail_large()).resize(240, 120).into(holder.tl);
        Picasso.with(context).load(liveList.get(position).getThumbnail_banner()).resize(120, 60).into(holder.tb);

        String video_url=liveList.get(position).getUrl();
        holder.url.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(video_url));


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return liveList.size();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <!-- Name Label -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#23e1b5"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/category_id"
        android:text="ZOOM"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="#23e1b5"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_id"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/id"
        android:text="10"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#23e1b5"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/id"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="MOVIES"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#942e8f"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/url"
        android:layout_below="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/url"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ts"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tb"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tl"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tb"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:text="Live"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#201b20"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/like"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/type"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tb"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#23e1b5"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tb"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/like"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#942e8f"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/watch"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tb"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#23e1b5"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try this [link](https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429#.9s1jfuurm)

Comment: Play video on click event of recyclerview Items.

and for play video use this library its very nice as i used too!
https://github.com/tcking/GiraffePlayer

Comment: Thanks for the answer,this player is good but i don't want to play video on click i want to play it on the same activity like FB.Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you came up to any solution?